# Regex for string separated by pipe character

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm having some problems coming up with a regexp that matches `class1`, `class2`, and `class3` in the following string (ideally I could have **n** number of words separated by pipes, as the number of classes passed to my method is not constant)

```
class1|class2|class3 path/to/resource
```

I have the following matcher which returns only `class1`. Bonus points to whomever can find me a matcher for the resource path as well.

**Edit**

Thank you very much for all the help - points all around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are confident that your input will be well formed, my advice would be to split your string by both the pipe character and space. For example:

```
components = "class1|class2|class3 path/to/resource".split(/[ \|]/)
```

You would then have access to an array containing n components followed by the path to your resource which you can manipulate to access.

```
resourcePath = components.pop()
classes = components
```

EDIT: The original topic of this was suggested the OP is using Ruby, hence my answer.

Comment: Seems I was approaching this problem all wrong - thank you very much! :-)

Comment: @Nicolay yes although it is possible to get what you wanted via regex I provided in my answer ; ) but Pat Teen's solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
\w+(\|\w+)*\s+\w+(\/\w+)*
```

I assumed that the names of your classes consist of one or more word characters. Adjust if they're more restricted than that. For instance, use `class\d+` for numbered classes only.

We have a class name, followed by any number of [a pipe followed by a class name]. Then we have one or more spaces, followed by basically the same thing, but this time using slashes instead of pipes.
I've escaped both the pipe and the slash with a backslash.

Comment: Checked it in two different regex compilers and C#, doesn't work in any case.

Comment: Ah, I see. I interpreted the OP's question as wanting to match the entire string, as per http://regexr.com?3771p

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "class1|class2|class3 path/to/resource".split(%r{[| ]})
```

=> ["class1", "class2", "class3", "path/to/resource"]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regex with the input you provided, this will extract your classes and path:

```
([\w/]+)\|? ?
```

**INPUT**

```
class1|class2|class3 path/to/resource
```

**OUTPUT**

```
class1
class2
class3
path/to/resource
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just do two splits:

```
string = 'class1|class2|class3 path/to/resource'

p string.split.first.split('|') #=> ["class1", "class2", "class3"]
```